# Find the number of ring homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}_{11} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{13}$ sending $1$ to $1$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Find the number of  ring  homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}_{11} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{13}$ sending $1$ to $1$.

My try : I think $1$ ring homomorphism .

Let $x= f(1_{11})$. Hence $ x = f(1_{11}) = f(1_{11}.1_{11}) = f(1_{11})f(1_{11})=x^2$. Thus  $x$  is an idempotent  of $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$ since  $\mathbb{Z_{13}}$ is an integral domain   so $0$  and $1_{13}$  are the only idempotents  of $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$

so  either  $x$  will be $0_{13}$ or $x= 1_{13}$

so there will be  one possible ring homomorphism that sending $1$ to $1$

Am I correct or not ?  If not correct please tell my mistakes

Comment: If you send $1$ to $1$, are there any theorems about the orders of an element and its image that might be applicable?

Comment: The only homomorphism is the trivial homomorphism. If $\phi: \mathbb{Z}_{11} \to \mathbb{Z}_{13}$ by $1_{11} \mapsto 1_{13}$, then it must be the case that $\phi(6_{11} + 6_{11}) = \phi(6_{11}) + \phi(6_{11}) = 6_{13} + 6_{13} = 12_{13}$, but on the otherhand $\phi(6_{11} + 6_{11}) = \phi(1_{11}) = 1_{13} \neq 12_{13}$.

Comment: i   don't  know about that  theorem @MichaelBurr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any ring homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Z}_{11} \to \mathbb{Z}_{13}$ is also a group homomorphism. The kernel of $\phi$ must have index dividing 11 and 13 (why?) and hence has index dividing $\gcd(13,11)=1$. Hence $\ker \phi= \mathbb{Z}_{11}$. And hence no group homomorphism sending $1_{11}$ to $1_{13}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** What happens if you add the equality $f(1_{11})=1_{13}$ to itself $13$ times?

Comment: I'd add it 11 times.

Comment: @user26857 that works too, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Since a ring homomorphism is a group homomorphism,  you can invoke Lagrange's theorem to get a contradiction.   That is, $\varphi (\Bbb Z_{11})\cong \Bbb Z_{11}/\operatorname {ker}\phi$, so has order dividing $11$.  But $\varphi (\Bbb Z_{11})\le\Bbb Z_{13}$.  Thus the image has order $1$, or $\varphi $ is trivial.